# How to pass a tensor type value to the shape argument of Variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I met a problem that can be summarised below:

```
foo = tf.constant(3)
foo_variable = tf.get_variable("foo", shape=[foo], dtype=tf.int32)
```

That the shape of the variable has to depend on the value of a tensor(`foo` here is only an abstraction of calculated result from other operations)

The error here is `The shape of a variable can not be a Tensor object`

How to resolve this?

Comment: Add on: I don't want the shape of tensor `foo`, but the value inside of `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tensor-initializer that has shape specified by your `foo` tensor and then instantiate a new variable using this initializer with `validate_shape=False`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=())
shape = tf.constant([2, 3]) + x
init = tf.zeros(shape, dtype=tf.int32)
v = tf.get_variable('foo', initializer=init, validate_shape=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), {x: 1})
    print(v.eval())
    # [[0 0 0 0]
    #  [0 0 0 0]
    #  [0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: I think ... you kinda misunderstood my intention. With `foo.get_shape().as_list()`, the shape of the variable is `[]`, while I hope the shape is `[3]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I eventually need to save the variable to a graph and I met another error, I wonder if you have an idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729579/how-to-save-a-tensorflow-graph-without-initialise-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

A tensorflow variable cannot have a dynamic shape but if you know the shape out of the session you could use:

```py
foo_variable = tf.get_variable("foo", shape=[], validate_shape=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(foo_variable, feed_dict={foo_variable: ones((2,2))}))
```