# How to save a tensorflow graph without initialise a variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The problem I encountered can be reflected as follow:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=())
init = tf.zeros(shape=tf.squeeze(x), dtype=tf.float32)

v = tf.get_variable('foo', initializer=init, validate_shape=False)


v_sig = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={"x_input": tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x)},
            outputs={
                'v_output': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(v)
            },
            method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir="~/test/")
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # here leads to problem
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            'v_sig': v_sig
        },
        main_op=tf.tables_initializer(),
        strip_default_attrs=True
    )
    builder.save()
```

I have a variable `foo` whose shape is calculated on the fly(depending on the input of placeholder `x`). When I tried to save it as a graph, I met error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype int32

If I don't run `global_variables_initializer`, it would has error `variable does not exists`.

So how to resolve the situation? I have been stuck on this for quite some time, appreciate for an answer.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to have, or use, or save a variable of variable size. It seems that what you are trying to use would have a regular tensor behavior, like the placeholder directly or a constant, although hard to say exactly without seeing how you are going to use that variable

Comment: You can have a variable with undetermined shape using `validate_shape=False`, as you are doing. However, the value that you are using for initialization depends on `x`, so you need to give a value for `x` when you run the initialization (e.g. `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict={x: [2, 3]})` to intialize to shape `(2, 3)`).

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply. Looks like tensor flow variable is not designed for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save your graph as meta graph object without initializing the variables like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import json

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(), name='x')
init = tf.zeros(shape=tf.squeeze(x), dtype=tf.float32, name='init')
v = tf.get_variable('foo', initializer=init, validate_shape=False)
tensor_names = {
    'x': x.name,
    'v': v.name
}
with open('tensor_names.json', 'w') as fo:
  json.dump(tensor_names, fo)

fname = 'graph.meta'
proto = tf.train.export_meta_graph(filename=fname,
                                   graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

And later restore this graph:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import json

with open('tensor_names.json', 'r') as fo:
  tensor_names = json.load(fo)

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  tf.train.import_meta_graph(fname)
  x = graph.get_tensor_by_name(tensor_names['x'])
  v = graph.get_tensor_by_name(tensor_names['v'])

# works as expected: 
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), {x:5})
  print(v.eval()) # [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```